# How to bind a TextBox to a particular field of a particular item in a BindingList?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged, bindinglist

Can a TextBox  be bound to a particular field of a particular item in a BindingList?

Here is a piece of code to illustrate the task:

```
public class MyItemClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
}

// ...

var item1 = MyItemClass { MyItemProperty1 = 123, MyItemProperty2 = "456" };

var item2 = MyItemClass { MyItemProperty1 = 789, MyItemProperty2 = "012" };

var bindingList = new BindingList<MyItemClass>();

bindingList.Add(item1);

bindingList.Add(item2);

var myFirstItemProperty2TextBox = new TextBox();

var my789ItemProperty2TextBox = new TextBox();

// myFirstItemProperty2TextBox.Text property
// should be bound to the MyItemProperty2 property of the very
// first item in bindingList if possible

// my789ItemProperty2TextBox.Text property
// should be bound to the MyItemProperty2 property of the
// first (or every) item in bindingList that has MyItemProperty1 property
// equal to "789" if possible

// In case the list item gets removed and another takes its place
// the text boxes should be re-bound to the new items
// that fits the criterion if possible

// Introducing additional helper controls/variables/delegates
// in between the list and the text boxes is acceptable if needed
// (not too much preferably)
```

Is this possible? If yes, how?

I actually am almost sure this is possible to achieve (with help of some intermediary logic at least) but the question in fact is about finding a considerably simple, efficient and reliable way.

I am interested in binding ComboBoxes (making use of the DisplayMember/ValueMember stuff) the same way too.

Comment: Try making use of the Name and/or Tag properties of the Controls. Set the Name string to something formulaic like you're doing with the variable names, then you'll be able to find it again in the Controls tree using built-in methods, or a little Linq, and you can dynamically bind/unbind its Text property. True "databinding" is more a WPF concept, but you can do dynamic WinForms almost as easily.

Comment: @KeithS The killer-problem of WPF is that is not cross-platform (WinForms can run on Mono, WPF can't). As for setting the names to "something formulaic" - I didn't intend this to be a part of the runtime logic but I'll consider this. Thanks.